# Bundling Flash or a Flash installer

Tags: flash

My company ships Windows software that has Flash as a dependency. Currently, we ask our users to separately install "Flash Player for other browsers" from [the official website](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/). This is not ideal.

Is it possible to ship Flash with our software? Maybe there is an installer that handles the different versions of Windows. What about a distribution license?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar task at work that we solved, among other things, by using MDM Zinc,
http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/

which is an exe wrapper fro swfs, which does a lot of cool "AIR" like things. We can run our Flash program on machines even if they do not have the Flash browser plugins. It's a few hundred dollars though.

Alternatively you can go the install script route. First download the redistributable flash:
http://www.adobe.com/special/products/flashplayer/fp_distribution3.html

Then run a batch file to launch it while installing your other stuff.

You could also accomplish this type of thing with a 3rd party installer packager, such as the free Inno installer.
http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

As far as licensing goes I would assume you are somewhat safe to include the Flash installer with your install media, since I can't foresee Adobe wanting to sue you over spreading their product to more clients:) Good to read the fine print regardless, you can find it here
http://www.adobe.com/products/clients/all_dist_agreement.html

Answer (score 0):

AIR runtime can be packaged with the program, Flash projector will naturally come with the version of the player that runs it, but browser plugin / activeX aren't redistributable so far I know. Not the latest versions anyway (I'm not sure on what basis Google Chrome updates the player, but it looks more like they have some sort of an agreement with Adobe).

This may be a difference in Windows and the rest of the PC users philosophy... but I wouldn't like a program modifying my browser setup out of it's own will. So, asking a user to update / install proper player seems to be the best approach to me.

BTW, you probably wanted to *ship* Flash ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute the flash installer with your app. This includes having the flash player installer included on a CD or DVD. No special license is needed. Here is their licensing page. Its very simple and clear language.
http://www.adobe.com/products/players/fpsh_distribution1.html

There are no fees, and the license is available to you without needing written consent from adobe for your use.